# Show that $\| x-x_j \|_2^2$ is equal to

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

I have a simple question. 
$$\|x-c_j\|_2^2 = x^T x-2x^T c_j+c_j^T c_j$$
Where $x,c_j\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $j=1,2,\ldots,n$.

I know that $$\|x-c_j\|_2^2=(x-c_1)^2+(x-c_2)^2+\cdots+(x-c_n)^2.$$
But I don't see relation between the transposed vector and the vector. Regards.

Comment: I think that your title should be: "Show that $||x-x_j||_2^2$ *is* equal to".

Comment: $x^Tx=x\cdot x$.

Comment: Are the $c_j$'s in the equation the same as the $x_j$'s?

Comment: @JimmyK4542 sorry, it was a mistake

Comment: If $x$ is a vector, your second equation does not make sense. Also, is $\{c_i\}_{i\in I}$ a basis of the space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question does not make completely sense as it is now, but I think this should help.
\begin{align}
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i-c_i)^2 &= \sum\limits_{i=1}^n (x_i^2 + c_i^2 -2x_i c_i)\\
&=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i^2 +\sum\limits_{i=1}^n c_i^2 - 2\sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i c_i \\
&=\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x} + \mathbf{c}^T\mathbf{c} - 2\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{c}.
\end{align}

---

Here we have used that
$$\mathbf{x}^T\mathbf{y} = \begin{pmatrix} x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} y_1\\ y_2 \\ \vdots \\ y_n\end{pmatrix}
 = \sum\limits_{i=1}^n x_i y_i.$$

Answer (score 0):

We have by definition

> $$
> \mathbf{x} =
> \left[
> \begin{array}{c}
> x_1 \\
> x_2 \\
> \vdots\\
> x_n
> \end{array}
> \right]
> $$

and

> $$
> \mathbf{x}^T =
> \big[
> x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n
> \big]
> $$

so we get

> $$
> \mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{x} =
> \big[
> x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n
> \big]
> \left[
> \begin{array}{c}
> x_1 \\
> x_2 \\
> \vdots\\
> x_n
> \end{array}
> \right]
> =
> x_1^2 + x_2^2 + \cdots + x_n^2
> $$